# android facebook UserSettingsFragment not working

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I am pretty new to android and facebook plugin.trying to follow the below steps as mentioned in facebook
  developer site.
  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/authenticate/
  Go to   Step 3.

```
   I followed it without missing any steps. 
   However, I do not see a menu at the bottom when i am logged in.Any help?

  Below is the snippet of important codes and xml.
@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // only add the menu when the selection fragment is showing
        if (fragments[SELECTION].isVisible()) {
            if (menu.size() == 0) {
                Log.d("onPrepareOptionsMenu","Yes");

                settings = menu.add(R.string.settings);
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            menu.clear();
            settings = null;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Following the main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <fragment android:name="com.punit.xxx.SelectionFragment"
          android:id="@+id/selectionFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <fragment android:name="com.punit.xxx.SplashFragment"
          android:id="@+id/splashFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <fragment android:name="com.facebook.widget.UserSettingsFragment"
          android:id="@+id/userSettingsFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to put some log and found that OnPrepareotionsMenu is never called.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) from your code.
2. Add

   ```
     *item
       android:id="@+id/action_logout"
       MyNews:showAsAction="never"
       android:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
       android:orderInCategory="10"
       android:title="@string/logout"/*
   ```

Note: replace * with < or >.

1. Add

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   ```

   ```
   switch(item.getItemId()){
   case R.id.action_logout:
       showSettingsFragment();
       return true;
   }
   return false;
   ```

   }
   public void showSettingsFragment(){
       showFragment(SETTINGS, true);
   }

It worked for me.

Comment: Is it supposed to say android instead of MyNews?

Comment: and do you add the <item> in the layout xml or the drawable? or somewhere else?